# Ansible multi hop design

Tags: ssh, ansible

I would like to run an ansible playbook on a target host passing through multiple hosts. The scenario looks similar to the one depicted in the picture:

[image]

I **partially** solved  issue creating the `ssh_config` file in the Ansible project directory:

```
Host IP_HostN
        HostName IP_HOST_N
        ProxyJump Username1@IP_HOST_2:22,Username2@IP_HOST_2:22
        User UsernameN
```

and defining in the `ansible.cfg` in the Ansible project directory:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args= -F "ssh_config"
```

The problem is that I need to insert automatically for each transient hosts and target host ssh **username** and **password** and I don't know how to automate this task. Moreover, **python may not be installed** on every transient node.

Comment: Sounds like a good reason to use [SSH agent forwarding](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html) with public key auth.

Comment: You can add password to `ssh_config` so you need to use keys as such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a reasonably good workaround. According to the scenario below:

[image]

we create an ssh tunnel until the transient host that can directly reach the target host. We also create a local port binding with **-L** flag:

```
ssh  -J user_1@transient_host1:port_1 -p port_2 user_2@transient_host2  -L LOCAL_PORT:TARGET_HOST_IP:TARGET_HOST_PORT
```

Then we can directly enter into Target Host using the local binding:

```
ssh user_target_host@localhost -p LOCAL_PORT
```

In this way, we can run **ansible** playbooks on the local host configuring ansible variables accordingly:

```
ansible_host: localhost
ansible_user: user_target_host
ansible_port: LOCAL_PORT
ansible_password: password_target_host
```